# .htaccess, can't rewrite url in LAMP

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, lamp

I have a problem rewriting a url. It seems that when I try to set GET value through `.htaccess` file it doesn't work, but when I do something like `localhost/project/?url=index/contact` it works.

This is my **.htaccess** file

```
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

    RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

My **project** looks like:

```
    --app/
    ----controllers/
    ----libraries/
    ----views/
    ----models/
    --public/
    ----css/
    ----images/
    index.php
    .htaccess
```

and **bootstrap** file:

```
class bootstrap
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $url = isset($_GET['url'])? $_GET['url'] : null;
        $url = rtrim($url, '/');
        $url = explode('/', $url);

        if(empty($url[0]))
        {
            require 'app/controllers/index.php';
            $controller = new index();
            $controller->indexAction();
            $controller->loadModel('index');
            $controller->view->render('index','index');
            return false;
        }

        $file = 'app/controllers/'.$url[0].'.php';
        if(file_exists($file))
        {
            require $file;
        }
        else
        {
            error::noController();
        }

        $controller = new $url[0]();
        $controller->loadModel($url[0]);

        if(!isset($url[1]))
        {
            if(method_exists($controller, 'indexAction'))
            {
                $viewFile = 'app/views/'.$url[0].'/index.phtml';
                if(file_exists($viewFile)) {
                    $controller->indexAction();
                    $controller->view->render($url[0],'index');
                }
                else
                    error::noView();
            }
            else
            {
                error::noMethod();
            }
        }

        if(isset($url[2]))
        {
            $action = $url[1].'Action';
            $controller->$action($url[2]);
            $controller->view->render($url[0], $url[1]);
        }
        else
        {   
            if(isset($url[1]))
            {
                $action = $url[1].'Action';
                if(method_exists($controller, $action))
                {
                    $controller->$action();
                    if(file_exists('app/views/'.$url[0].'/'.$url[1].'.phtml'))
                        $controller->view->render($url[0],$url[1]);
                    else
                        error::noView();
                }
                else
                {
                    error::noMethod();
                }
            }
        }
    }
    }
?>
```

Comment: Have you debugged with `var_dump($_GET)`? Your .htaccess contents look correct, assuming you have no other rewrite rules in there. Have you verified that the .htaccess file is parsed to begin with (that `AllowOverride` is correctly set for the server/virtualhost)?

Comment: result of this var_dump is "array (0) {}" and i set allowoverride to all

Comment: I've noticed that when I type for example "contact" in my url, it works properly. Problem starts when I type "index", then $_GET array is empty

Comment: Do you have `MultiViews` enabled in Apache for that directory? That might cause problems with `/index`

Comment: Disabling `MultiViews` has helped, thank you.